# Lodash _.sortByOrder numeric string

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I sort collection of objects with single primary key:

```
mydata = _.sortBy(mydata, function (obj) {
    return parseInt(obj[pk], 10);
});
```

But I cannot sort this numeric strings when is a composite key like `["RHID","CD_DOC_ID","SEQ"]`

Comment: Please provide a sample of `mydata`, and the expected output.

Comment: try _.sortBy(mydata);

Comment: mydata is array of objects. here is an object             {
  "RHID": "1",
  "CD_DOC_ID": "1",
  "SEQ": "1",
  "NR_DOCUMENTO": "3333",
  "EMISSOR": "Lisboas643223",
  "DT_EMISSAO": "2004-01-12",
  "DT_VALIDADE": "2014-12-17",
  "NOME_FICHEIRO": "1EV5.pdf"
}    and i want to sort by the first tree propertie that are an array

Comment: The problem is that the values are strings

Comment: you want to sort your  { "RHID": "1", "CD_DOC_ID": "1", "SEQ": "1", "NR_DOCUMENTO": "3333", "EMISSOR": "Lisboas643223", "DT_EMISSAO": "2004-01-12", "DT_VALIDADE": "2014-12-17", "NOME_FICHEIRO": "1EV5.pdf" } object with ["RHID","CD_DOC_ID","SEQ"] array?

Answer (score 5):

In Lodash v3 do:

```
mydata = _.sortByAll(
  mydata, 
  [
    function (obj) {
      return parseInt(obj["RHID"], 10);
    },
    function (obj) {
      return parseInt(obj["CD_DOC_IC"], 10);
    },
    function (obj) {
      return parseInt(obj["SEQ"], 10);
    }
  ]
);
```

In Lodash v4:
replace `_.sortByAll` with `_.sortBy`

If you also want to specify the sorting direction, use `_.sortByOrder` (v3) or `_.orderBy` (v4) instead.